# What is pancha angni yajna in agnihotra?

Tags: yajna, vedic-rituals, homam

1. What is pancha kunda in agnihotra?
   anvahrya, grahapathy, dakshinaagni and uttravedhi in agnihotra
2. what is their respective  meaning with short description of the offerings made?
3. Is Vaishwadeva homa a part of agnihotra?